# Leading Zeroes are dropping from gridcomplete

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am loading varchar(10) values that may have leading zeroes, as key fields for lookup. In the grid the values display with the leading zeroes. When the key value is passed to the function, through the select, the zeroes are missing.

```
        gridComplete: function () {
        var ids = jQuery("#grdProductGrid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            var cl = ids[i];
            var rowId = $("#grdProductGrid").getRowData(cl);
            be = "<a href='#'>Product</a >";
            be = "<a href='#' onclick='GetProduct(" + rowId['ID'] + ")'>Product</a >";
```

When I get to the GetProduct function the leading zeroes are missing.

Is there a string function I am missing when I load the selects? Or should I be doing something else here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't passing the ID as a string to `GetProduct`.

`be = "<a href='#' onclick='GetProduct(" + rowId['ID'] + ")'>Product</a >";` will generate a link that looks something like this:

`<a href='#' onclick='GetProduct(000123)'>Product<a/>`

000123 isn't a string literal there, so javascript is thinking it's a number.  Try this when creating the links:

`be = "<a href='#' onclick='GetProduct(\"" + id + "\")'>Product</a >";`

I added the `\"` in side the parentheses of `GetProduct`.  This will generate a link that looks like:

`<a href='#' onclick='GetProduct("000123")'>Product<a/>`

See this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/deSGV/ (outputs into the console).

Comment: I tried your solution but the onclick event doesn't work now.

Comment: How did you verify it isn't working?  Have you looked at the rendered link?  Did you use a console.log or an alert or breakpoint in the `GetProduct` function to verify it isn't getting called?

Comment: Once I looked and the jsfiddle more carefully I moved the "\" into the parenthesis as opposed to the above code. That solevd the issue.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I had the correct code in the Fiddle.  Copy/paste issue.